# How to access data from parent widget?

Tags: flutter

I have this screen which displays user profile:

```
class DisplayProfile extends StatefulWidget {

  final UserProfile profile; // profile contains name and email

  const DisplayProfile({Key? key, required this.profile}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DisplayProfileState createState() {
    return _DisplayProfileState();
  }
}

class _DisplayProfileState extends State<DisplayProfile> {

    Widget profileWidget() {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: <
            Widget>[
          Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          child: Text("Name",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
          Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          child: Text(profile.name,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
          Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          child: Text("E-mail",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
          Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          child: Text(profile.email,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
        ]));
      }
      
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
          top: false,
          child: Scaffold(
          ....
          )
        )
      }
  }
```

Of course, the code above won't compile. Flutter complains:

> The getter 'name' isn't defined for the type '_DisplayProfileState'.

How to make **profile** in DisplayProfile accessible from _DisplayProfileState?

Comment: does my answer work for you?

Comment: Yes it works. I replaced TextField with TextFormField, then problem is solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `widget` before profile as follows:

```
 Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          child: Text(widget.profile.name,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
          Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          child: Text("E-mail",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
          Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          child: Text(widget.profile.email,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
```

Comment: Sorry. I copied paste the wrong section. I actually use TextField instead of Text, like this: ` Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          child: TextField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: widget.profile.name,
               border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          )))`. Flutter complains: invalid constant value